# How to solve the "Camera" is not multi-view error"?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I am confused on why the camera suddenly states that it is not a multi-view camera. It was working fine days before until now. I saw another forum that states adding another camera can be a solution. I tried that, not sure if I did it right. I would like a step by step guideline if possible. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do one of this:

1) Set **Stereo 3D** instead of **Multi-View**, if you want to use one camera

2) Or if you select  **Multi-View** add as many cameras as you have **views** here:

[image]

and add a suffix to camera names from **camera suffix** setting. Like in my case, I have 2 views and set up 2 cameras:

[image]

Comment: One issue with the Stereo 3D is that it makes weird 3D colors, which I don't want. I only want it to render normally.

Comment: @ShiningLuna  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkZQQxl2xYE